# Preferred way to initialize a class in Swift

Tags: class, swift, initialization, init

In learning Swift, there seems to be two approaches to initializing a class instance:

```
// Approach A

class Person {
    let first: String = "bob"
    let last: String = "barker"
}

let worker = Person()
worker.first
worker.last

// Approach B

class Person2 {
    let first2: String
    let last2: String

    init() {
        self.first2 = "bill"
        self.last2 = "williams"
    }
}

let dealer = Person2()
dealer.first2
dealer.last2
```

Is there any reason why I would use one approach instead of the other?

Comment: Pick one and stick to it. Personally I would NEVER do what you have in A (unless Im being lazy or testing something). Better to put initializations in a method so its clear to the reader where those values are set.

Comment: Why would you even try to create a class with fixed property values?

Comment: @Abizern this is meant to be an example of ways to initialize class properties, not to illustrate whether or not a certain property should be a `var` or `let`

Comment: If it makes sense to have default values for properties then set them when declaring the property. If not, then set them in the initialiser. It's not that difficult a choice if you think about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“If a property always takes the same initial value, provide a default value rather than setting a value within an initializer. The end result is the same, but the default value ties the property’s initialization more closely to its declaration. It makes for shorter, clearer initializers and enables you to infer the type of the property from its default value. The default value also makes it easier for you to take advantage of default initializers and initializer inheritance, as described later in this chapter.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: +1 Also found online here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Answer (score 5):

I use the first version when I have a known default value that I am putting into the variable. I use the second for anything that could change based on what I pass into the init.

So my preferred version of the above would be:

```
// Approach A

class Person {
    let first: String = "bob"
    let last: String = "barker"
}

let worker = Person()
worker.first
worker.last

// Approach B

class Person2 {
    let first2: String
    let last2: String

    init(first2: String, last2: String) {
        self.first2 = first2
        self.last2 = last2
    }
}

let dealer = Person2(first2: "bill", last2: "williams")
dealer.first2
dealer.last2
```