# Initialize a class in Swift

Tags: swift, class, variables, initialization

Maybe this is super basic stuff, but I'm still not sure the difference between the following codes in Swift.

- `private let myViewController = MyViewController()`
- `private let myViewController: MyViewController!`

I used them interchangeably when I make a variable in Swift, but is there a difference between them? Also, is there a specific name for the way it is initialized? (I want to do some Google search for the difference between the code above, but since I'm not sure the name of the initialization, I can't Google search now...).

Comment: THIS MIGHT HELP YOU  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696134/preferred-way-to-initialize-a-class-in-swift

Comment: The second one doesn't instantiate a `MyViewController` at all. "I used them interchangeably when I make a variable in Swift" <-- Try changing the places where you have used the first one to use the second one instead. You'd definitely get some crashes, if not compiler errors. You'll see how non-interchangeable these two are.

Comment: Time to do some [reading](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`private let myViewController = MyViewController()`
means `myViewController` have instance of `MyViewController` class whenever it will be used in class.

But `private let myViewController: MyViewController!` in that case we must assign the instance of `MyViewController` to `myViewController` before using `myViewController` otherwise there will be a crash.

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com 
Thank you so much for the quick response! 
I think I get the difference: if it has an instance or not. So I feel using the first one with instance is pretty useful when I need to initialize the class, because the second one with ! sign must assign the instance again, but is there a useful case I should use "private let myVC: MyVC!" ?
Since I must assign the instance to it, I feel the first one with instantiation is pretty useful...

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! 
I think I get the difference: if it has an instance or not. So I feel using the first one with instance is pretty useful when I need to initialize the class, because the second one with ! sign must assign the instance again, but is there a useful case I should use "private let myVC: MyVC!" ?
Since I must assign the instance to it, I feel the first one with instantiation is pretty useful...

Comment: @Yuuu second line can be used when you need that instance in some cases not in all class. So, in that case you initailize that instance and use it.